# tree traversal runtime and space analysis general approach

Tags: algorithm, complexity-theory, space-complexity, code-complexity

I am currently on [94. Binary Tree Traversal](https://leetcode.com/problems/binary-tree-inorder-traversal/) on leetcode and I am not sure how to analyze the run time and space complexity of the question. In my opinion, the time complexity for the question seems to be O(n) where n is number of node in the tree, since we need to traverse every single node in the tree. However, for space it is more controversial, I think it is O(h), where h is the max height of the tree, because I think the call stack incurred by recursion can go as far as max height of the tree, and the stack will pop as we backtrack. Some people suggest it is actually O(n), because in the worst case where the tree is completely left or rightly skewed, the call stack is as deep as the number of node available, but isn't O(h) also works here since max height is also the number of node in the tree. While O(n) is the worst case but O(h) seems more accurate and fit more scenario including the example above, which one is should be the answer? Or more specifically, which one would be accepted by interviewer during coding interview?

I will also paste my solution here:

```
class Solution {
public List < Integer > inorderTraversal(TreeNode root) {
    List < Integer > res = new ArrayList < > ();
    helper(root, res);
    return res;
}

public void helper(TreeNode root, List < Integer > res) {
    if (root != null) {
        if (root.left != null) {
            helper(root.left, res);
        }
        res.add(root.val);
        if (root.right != null) {
            helper(root.right, res);
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

The space complexity is always O(n), even when the tree is balanced. This is because both the *input* as the *output* have a size of O(n). The *output* is *newly* allocated memory, so even if we would ignore the memory already taken by the input, the algorithm would still be using O(n) additional memory.

If we don't count the memory needed for the output either, then indeed the space complexity is O(h).

Now, it is less common to use the height of the input tree as a parameter for asymptotic complexity. It is more common to use the number of nodes for that purpose.

But either would be OK to mention during an interview, as long as you are clear about *which* space is intended: is it only about *auxiliary* space? ... excluding the auxiliary space that the output may occupy?